# Regular expression in python to get the last occurence of a file extension in a URL or path

Tags: python, regex

Given a long url or path how do I get the last file extension in it. For example consider these two strings.

```
url = 'https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/vector-chickens-full-emotions_75487-787.jpg?x=2'
path = './image.freepik.com/free-vector/vector-chickens-full-emotions_75487-787.abc.jpg'
```

The last extension is `jpg` and comes after the last `.` and before the following non-alphanumerics or end-of-string.

There are similar questions to mine but I can't find an exact match.

Comment: so, you're looking for .jpg or .abc (or abc) in the above example?

Comment: I can recommend [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for all your regex needs. Put your string in there and see whether your can match it. Don't be afraid to experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
re.search('\.(\w+)(?!.*\.)', url).group(1)
```

Use negative lookahead to search for matches that aren't followed by dots

Answer (score 1):

Parsing rules are different for FILENAMES, and URLS - so don't make a single REGEX to do that, its not simple and not worth your time.

Instead, make a test of some sort - to determine what type of object you are looking at, ie: This *IS* or *ISNOT* a URL. This could be as simple as: Does it start with http://, then it is a URL.. if not ... it is not a URL

Then apply the specific rule to the specific type.

Always make use of standard tools, they have often already figured out the corner cases or things you will forget.

The URL parser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Then, for files use: os.path.splitext(path)
in the standard python library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: Thanks. Developing your answer we get for a path that ```Path(path).suffix``` works where we ```from pathlib import Path```, and for a url that ```Path(urlparse(url).path).suffix``` works where we ```from urllib.parse import urlparse``` and ```from pathlib import Path```.